# Could not find carrierwave-1.0.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, carrierwave

## Impossible to use carrierwave gen, message :

> Could not find carrierwave-1.0.0 in any of the sources
>
> Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

But the gem seems to be installed ...

```
In the Gemfile of my rails project :
ruby '2.3.1'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
...
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
...

> gem install carrierwave         
Successfully installed carrierwave-1.0.0
1 gem installed

> bundle install 
...
Using carrierwave 1.0.0
...
Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 78 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

> bundle show carrierwave
 /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave-1.0.0

> rails g uploader Photo   
Could not find carrierwave-1.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

> bundle update
...
Using carrierwave 1.0.0
...
Bundle updated!

> rails g uploader Photo 
Could not find carrierwave-1.0.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: issue fixed after reboot ...

Answer (score 0):

Execute `rails g` command in the context of the bundle

`bundle exec rails g uploader Photo`

Comment: This answer was flagged for removal. It should not be removed, but I believe you should explain what this is doing and how it answers the question.

Comment: Thanks @alex but already try with bundle exec, but same issue.